# Drawing and interacting with a grid of boxes on iPhone / iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I have an idea for an iPhone game that basically involves interacting with a grid of squares (think [letterpress](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/letterpress-word-game/id526619424?mt=8))

What would be the easiest way to create a grid of coloured squares that can be interacted with by touch?

UIKit, Cocos2d or some other means like OpenGL? I understand the benefits of UIKit would be that I would be able to get touch events for each box (if I made them an object/container etc) but may not be as fast as cocos2d and I probably have far less control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with UIKit, a random "Grid Component" framework *could* do the job for you. For example there's [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView), which has touch handling and everything you probably need out of the box already. (Just check out the example project provided with GMGridView)